# Is it possible to find with samba what version of windows is remote PC running?

Tags: windows, samba

As Microsoft stops supporting Windows XP next April, I was asked to check which PCs are still running with a version of Windows older than Windows 7. Is it possible via some Samba query to find out the version of a client's OS?

Comment: nmap's os detection (-o switch) would also probably work for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is:

nmap's os detection (-o switch) would also probably work for this.

Although as others said the best way to do it depends on your systems configuration.

Answer (score 8):

You're asking us how to make pork chops when all you have is a pound of ground beef. There's no good reason to use Samba for this, IMO.

If they're on an AD domain, the clients have stored their OS version in the OperatingSystem attribute of their computer objects. Using the ActiveDirectory Powershell module:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties OperatingSystem | Select Name, OperatingSystem
```

If they're not in an AD domain, then check each computer individually with something like this:

```
$Creds = Get-Credential
Foreach($_ In Get-Content  .\servers.txt)
{
    Get-WMIObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $_ -Credential $Creds | Select PSComputerName, Caption
}
```

Or if you're in an enterprise that has more high-end management tools installed, something like System Center Configuration Manager will tell you this information in a snap.

As will practically any other monitoring or configuration management system.

*Anything* except what you're trying to use.

If you need to do this from Linux for some reason, I'd suggest using wmic, which last I heard has an RPM package:

```
rpm -ivh wmic-4.0.0tp4-0.x86_64.rpm

wmic -U [domain/]adminuser%password //host "select Caption from Win32_OperatingSystem"
```

Comment: +1 for the first sentence.  I was trying earlier to figure out a proper response that would sound nice.  Nice job.

Comment: I never said that the PCs were in AD domain, did I. Thanks to comment of Jure1873 - indeed nmap did the job. If he would put it no as comment he will got my "accepted answer". And talking about "pork chops" - why should I kill a fly with a gun? ;-)

Comment: Not including details like that in the first place is why your question has downvotes. Nevertheless, I tried to guess and included *three* possible solutions, only one of which assumes an AD domain and one of the other two is a Linux-based one. Oh well, can't win 'em all. Despite all that, I hope that Jure1873 comes back and turns their comment into an answer. I'll upvote it, and you can accept it.